# Identify whether two companies are the same

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to solve a problem where I need to map multiple variations of a company name to a single name. For example: say I have a company named `Super Idea Corporation Limited`.

I need to resolve the following to `Super Idea Corporation Limited`

- SICL
- Super Idea Corp Ltd
- SIC Ltd
- SIC Limited

Is there a non regex way of doing this? The reason I am averse to using regex is that there are a lot of business names that can be represented in many different ways. I want something that is more flexible and adaptive.

Comment: You probably need a dictionary for common abbreviations (Limited -> Ltd, etc) and of course an acronym search to start with.

Comment: I assume that this task is quite difficult, even for a human: Consider [Man group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_Group) and [MAN SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAN_SE), what company is MAN  ? It depends on the context..

Answer (score 1):

**If** the number of permutations is known and final you can go with something like the below

```
SICL = 'Super Idea Corporation Limited'
lookup = {'SICL': SICL, 'Super Idea Corp Ltd': SICL, 'SIC Ltd': SICL}
```

**else** - you can use [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) . See [here](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/nltk.edit_distance.html) for python lib.

Comment: `If the number of permutations is known` that's precisely the issue. And with thousands of such names and new names coming in everyday, the permutations seem endless. Hence looking for a way that allows coming in of new names and eliminates manually creating lookup tables